# Pick values by dragging in PyQt5 and store it in a list

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm making an app using PyQt5 that I can pick values by dragging from 1 position to another position like this image:

[image]

All the values were picked will be stored in a list like:

```
[['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2'], ['4.7', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2'], .... ['4.4', '2.9', '1.4', '0.2']]
```

And when I drag to pick the new values, it will create a new list and store all data in that list

Can you guys show me how to implement?

Here is all the code:

```
import sys, os 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QTableWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
    QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Table Example')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        # Create a table, create a box layout, add the table to box layout and
        # then set the overall widget layout to the box layout.
        #
        self.createTable()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget) 
        self.setLayout(self.layout) 

        self.show()

    # Create a table with alphabet header labels. We're attempting to mimic
    # the classic spreadsheet look. This goes back to VisiCalc on the Apple ][
    # introduced in 1979.
    #
    def createTable(self):

        self.maxRows = 99
        self.headerLabels = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L",
            "M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.maxRows)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(self.headerLabels))
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.headerLabels)

        # Pre-populate the cells in the spreadsheets with data, strings in
        # this example.
        #
        for row in range(0, self.maxRows):
            for col in range(0, len(self.headerLabels)):
                self.tableWidget.setItem( row, col,
                    QTableWidgetItem("Cell {0}{1}".format(self.headerLabels[col], row+1)))
                #
                # Set every other row a light green color to help readability.
                #
                # if row % 2 != 0:
                #     self.tableWidget.item(row,col).setBackground(QColor(220,255,220))

        self.tableWidget.move(0,0)

        self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()

        # Hook various events to their respective callbacks.
        #
        self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.cellClicked)
        self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.cellChanged)
        self.tableWidget.cellActivated.connect(self.cellActivated)
        self.tableWidget.cellEntered.connect(self.cellEntered)
        self.tableWidget.cellPressed.connect(self.cellPressed)


    def cellClicked(self):
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print(' Clicked:', currentQTableWidgetItem.row(),
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.column(),
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.text())

    def cellChanged(self):
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print(' Changed:', currentQTableWidgetItem.row(),
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.column(),
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.text())
            list_value.append(currentQTableWidgetItem.text())

        print(list_value)

    def cellActivated(self):
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print(' Activated:', currentQTableWidgetItem.row(),
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.column(),
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.text())

            list_value.append(currentQTableWidgetItem.text())

    def cellEntered(self):

        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print(' Entered:', currentQTableWidgetItem.row(),
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.column(),
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.text())

    def cellPressed(self):
        global list_value
        list_value = []
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print('Pressed:', currentQTableWidgetItem.row(),
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.column(),
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.text())
            list_value.append(currentQTableWidgetItem.text())
        print(list_value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    print('PID',os.getpid())

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And actually what I got

[image]

I'm stuck with button press event, on pick event, on release event

Comment: @eyllanesc what link? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a property that is the list of the selected elements that must be modified when the selection that is notified through the itemSelectionChanged signal changes.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QTableWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
    QVBoxLayout,
)


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Table Example")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self._selected_lists = []

        self.createTable()
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

        self.show()

    def createTable(self):

        self.maxRows = 99
        self.headerLabels = [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E",
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "J",
            "K",
            "L",
            "M",
            "N",
            "O",
            "P",
            "Q",
            "R",
            "S",
            "T",
            "U",
            "V",
            "W",
            "X",
            "Y",
            "Z",
        ]
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.maxRows)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(self.headerLabels))
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.headerLabels)
        for row in range(0, self.maxRows):
            for col in range(0, len(self.headerLabels)):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(
                    row,
                    col,
                    QTableWidgetItem(
                        "Cell {0}{1}".format(self.headerLabels[col], row + 1)
                    ),
                )
        self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()

        self.tableWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.on_selection_changed)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_selection_changed(self):
        self._selected_lists = []
        indexes = self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes()
        rows = [index.row() for index in indexes]
        columns = [index.column() for index in indexes]

        row_min, row_max = min(rows), max(rows)
        col_min, col_max = min(columns), max(columns)

        p = []
        for r in range(row_min, row_max + 1):
            q = []
            for c in range(col_min, col_max + 1):
                text = self.tableWidget.model().index(r, c).data()
                q.append(text if text is not None else "")
            p.append(q)
        self._selected_lists = p

        print(self.selected_lists)

    @property
    def selected_lists(self):
        return self._selected_lists


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```